# Retrieve value of a Sharepoint Choice Field in c# Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

On an EventReceiver, using c# I want to retrieve all the selected values in a Sharepoint 2010 Choice field on a List.  Can anyone advise/provide a code snippet on how to read all the values from a Choice field?

Thanks

Comment: Check this [Get SharePoint Choice Field Value In C#](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/get-sharepoint-choice-field-value-in-c/)

Answer (score 6):

See this blog post. This is the proper way of doing this.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/10257/

```
SPFieldMultiChoiceValue choices = new SPFieldMultiChoiceValue(item["MultiChoice"].ToString());
for (int i = 0; i < choices.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(choices[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Choice column, where multiple Items can be chosen, you can use this to separate them:

```
string values = item["yourColumn"] as string;
string[] choices = null;
if (values != null)
{
    choices = values.Split(new string[] { ";#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Comment: Revisiting my answer after almost three years, I see how dirty the approach was. You should use @Sia's answer, it is the clean way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure as what you want to do. If you want to get all of the values from a field (choice) from a list i could suggest you get the list in to a object(SPList), iterate through the items (yourSPListObject.items)

```
// get the current web you are in
SPWeb objWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb();
//get your list
SPList lstYourInfoList = objWeb.Lists["<ListNameHere"];

//Iterate through the items in the list
foreach(SPListItem item in lstYourInfoList.items){
//pick out your information needed
string choiceSelected = item["<ColumnNamethatrepresentsyourchoicefield>"].ToString();
//store your information somewhere
//store the string in a local list and pass this list back out
}
```

This may help if you want to get all the choices that the user can select from

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/SharePoint-Choice-Field--Fetch-Each-Choice-Item-80.php

hope this answers your Q